# Kotlin coroutine: how switch to UI thread and wait for callback

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Process is on a background thread (async)

I want to open up a message box so user can tap Yes or No

After user taps Yes or No, a callback is performed (with result), then I want to continue the background async process.

I'm not sure how to do this.

I use suspendCoroutine to convert a callback function to something I can await.
But suspendCourtine is running on background thread, not UI thread.

Calling something like `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` inside suspendCoroutine doesn't compile.

```
// async function called from background thread
// I want the function to return AFTER user taps Yes or No

suspend fun showPopupYesNoAsync(title: String) : Boolean  {
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        // Problem is that here I'm on background thread and I can't open UI popup view
        openPopupYesNo(title= title) { tappedButton ->
            continuation.resume(tappedButton.id == "Yes")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you should do the opposite of what you tried - put `suspendCoroutine()` inside `withContext()`:

```kotlin
suspend fun showPopupYesNoAsync(title: String) : Boolean  {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            openPopupYesNo(title= title) { tappedButton ->
                continuation.resume(tappedButton.id == "Yes")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your process is on Background thread, we can assume

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        //Some process
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(globalContext)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("This is a message")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, which ->
                proceedWorking()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, which -> dialog.dismiss() }
            .show()
    }
    job.await()
}
```

Invoke another method either suspend or another coroutine to continue your task as follow:

```
private fun proceedWorking() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    // Your new process after confirmation
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I am curious to know how this does not block the main thread?